# payroll : adding multiple array values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The question is to create a program that asks the user to input how many employees. Then with each employee, a name, hour pay rate, hours worked is entered. the results of the employee pay, overtime pay and total pay is calculated.

My dilemma is how to find the total of all the pays. all employees pay, all employees overtime pay and all employees total pay

ex. user input: 2 employees (creates two arrays)
two inputs(name, rate, hours worked) will be entered
two results (pay, overtime pay, total pay) will be calculated
how do you add the pays, the overtime pays and total pays from both employees?

this is the code ive come up with, but it needs work

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class paycheck {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of Employees: ");
        int numberOfEmp= input.nextInt();

        int[] arrayList= new int[numberOfEmp];
         for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){

        System.out.print("Enter Employee Name: ");
        String empName= input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter hourly rate: ");
        int rate= input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");  
        int hours=input.nextInt();

       if (hours >=40)
   {
       double regPay=  hours * rate;
       double otPay = (hours-40) *(rate*1.5);
       double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
       System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+"\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
   }

        else
   {
       double regPay=  hours * rate;
       double otPay =0;
       double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
       System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+ "\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
    }

    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you keep three different variables , say allsalary , allovertime , allpay and keep on adding whenever any new employee is entered .

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an employee object that holds the values you want to track.
2. Create an ArrayList of employees.
3. Create a while loop that allows the user to input a employee's info, and then asks the user if they would like to continue or stop.  If they want to stop exit the loop and print your data.

If you create an employee object, you might want to give it a few static variables to keep track of total_pay, total_ot_pay, and other "totals" you want to track.